# mi textarea no reconoce mi clase

Tags: css, html5

tengo un documento php en donde tengo el siguiente codigo

```
    '<textarea class='futuro' name='comentarios' placeholder='Escribe tus comentarios'  onBlur='this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();'  required></textarea>'
```

y en le CCS tengo lo siguiente

```
   '.futuro{
width:250px;
height:45px;
border-radius:6px;
border:2px solid #ccc;
padding: 0px 10px}'
```

mas sin embargo no reconoce esta clase, ahora bien tengo otra clase llamada ftextarea250 y esa la reconoce a la perfecccion, la clase ftextarea250 es la siguiente

```
   '.ftextarea250{
width:250px;
height:45px;
border-radius:6px;
border:2px solid #ccc;
padding: 0px 10px;}'
```

alguien tiene alguna idea de que estoy haciendo mal ????

Comment: ¿querrás decir CSS?

Comment: hahahaha... ok error de dedo por escribir rapido, pero la pregunta esta clara no ?

Comment: me apena decir que ya encontre el error.... un simple ; al final de la etiqueta disculpen ustedes, me voy al rincon con el sombrero de burro

Comment: Si era un simple error, puedes borrar la pregunta entonces, gracias.

Comment: haaaaaaaaaaaaaa que crees que ni agregandole el punto y coma me lo sigue reconociendo, mejor ayudame en vez de criticarme.... 8..(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<textarea class='futuro' name='comentarios' placeholder='Escribe tus comentarios' onBlur='this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();' required></textarea>
```

CSS:

```
.futuro {
 width: 250px;
 height: 45px;
 border-radius: 6px;
 border: 2px solid #ccc;
 padding: 0 10px
}
```

Debería funcionar con esto.

Comment: Solo por curiosidad, ¿qué cambiaste con respecto al código original?

Comment: pense que era el punto y coma que debe de ir al final del  padding pero aun asi no corria, ahora bien acabo de probar el codigo en una ventana de incognito de chrome y si jala el codigo creo que solo es un maldito error de que no refresca bien mi navegador...